# onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Symfony/VueJS component

```
<template>
    <h1>OTHER-USER-PAGE</h1>
    <button @click="changeRoute(`/other/1`)">OTHER 1</button>
    <button @click="changeRoute(`/other/2`)">OTHER 2</button>
    <button @click="changeRoute(`/other/3`)">OTHER 3</button>
    <hr>
    {{ user }}
</template>



<script setup>
// IMPORTS
import { computed, onMounted, watch} from "vue";
import { useRoute, useRouter } from "vue-router";
import getUser from "../hooks/getUser"

// PROPS
const props = defineProps({ userId:{required:true} })

// VARS
const route     = useRoute()
const router    = useRouter()
const routeId   = computed(() => route.params.id)
const user      = getUser(props.userId)

// FUNCTIONS
const changeRoute = (value) => router.push(value)

// WATCH
watch(route,() => {
    console.log(routeId.value)

    // I ADD THIS CODE BELOW, ERROR SHOWS UP
    getUser(routeId)
})
</script>
```

../hooks/getUser

```
import { onMounted, ref }   from "vue"
import axios                from "axios"

export default function getUser(id){
    // VARS
    const user = ref()

    // FUNCTIONS
    const getUser = async() => {
        await axios
            .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
            .then(r  => user.value = r.data)
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }

    // ON-MOUNTED
    onMounted(() => (id) ? getUser(id) : false )

    // RETURNS
    return { user }
}
```

Symfony template file

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello OtherController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div {{ vue_component('OtherUserPage',{'userId':symfony_route_id}) }}></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Symfony Controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class OtherController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/other/{id}', name: 'app_other',defaults:['id'=>null])]
    public function index($id): Response
    {
        return $this->render('other/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'OtherController',
            'symfony_route_id' => $id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Good day JS,VUE profis,
Please help me to solve the issue.
I'm getting this error

**[Vue warn]: onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.**

anybody could advise me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: your code looks ok, can you provide the whole code for the component?

Comment: Spasibo, Alex, I was testing and removed code, let me construct it, 1 sec please

Comment: you could have this error in another place or you could have a wrong component code besides you've shown here

Comment: updated code, the main reason is, I'm trying to have "getUser" (function,hook) in a different file, to make Vue Component as short as possible.
This Vue is used as controllers/component inside Symfony app

Comment: if I put "getUser" (hook, function) into component as method/function everything works fine, I separate this function as hook to another file ../hooks/getUser.js, error shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All life-cycle hooks should be executed synchronously inside `<script setup>`. That's because in this time the hooks knows what is the current component is to hook into.

Also any other code not executed during `<script setup>` will cause that error.

In this code you violate this, by executing it asynchronously on a route change (getUser executes onMounted):

```
watch(route,() => {
    console.log(routeId.value)

    // I ADD THIS CODE BELOW, ERROR SHOWS UP
    getUser(routeId)
})
```

Btw you don't need async/await since you already return a promise:

```
const getUser = () => axios
            .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
            .then(r  => user.value = r.data)
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Or use async/await as supposed (without then/catch):

```
const getUser = async() => {
        try {
          user.value = (await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)).data;
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Btw you don't need `onMounted` hook at all, just fetch a user:

```
export default function getUser(id){

    const user = ref();

    axios
            .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
            .then(r  => user.value = r.data)
            .catch(e => console.log(e));

    return { user }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, Spasibo Alex, let me try this solution, I appriciate your advice

Comment: appriciate your advice Alex, I'll definitely do "accepted", but I need to fully test it, Thank You again

Comment: @yotokg no problem, just don't use onMounted like shown in the last code snippet

Comment: Alex, (all about ..hooks/getUser.js) the hook "getUser()" without "onMounted"  returning to Component "user: undefined (Ref)" , but when I put on onMounted(() => getUser(id)), the hook returns user object with data

Comment: @yotokg that's right, it works the same as with onMounted(). if you don't like undefined, create some default object: `const user = ref({})`